# Signal assignments from multiple if statements

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Out of academic interest, is the following code acceptable:

```
logic a, b, c;
int out;
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  out <= 1;
  if (a) out <= 2;
  if (b) out <= 3;
  if (c) out <= 3;
end
```

Inside always-block things should be sequential, right? So, in this example by
default **out** would be 1 but **a**, **b** and **c** could override the value
in "prioritized" order.

Or is there a risk of unknown result in synthesis? I.e. the order of assignments
would be random like this:

```
  if (c) out <= 3;
  out <= 1;
  if (b) out <= 3;
  if (a) out <= 2;
```

In this case, even if **c** was 1 **out** would be 1 (or something else if **a** or **b** are 1).

Comment: Someone might be asking, why would somebody code something like this? The reason is, that sometimes if-else structures can get really complex and just having a "default" value for a signal defined is nice. Also, the if-statement size and complexity increases if the statement has to consider all the possibilities all the time just to drive one signal into certain value. And this easily opens doors to bugs and other surprising features.

Answer (score 2):

When you have code inside a `begin/end` block, the statements are guaranteed to execute in serial order. And with non-blocking assignment, the result is predictable when the statement order is predictable. So you get the prioritized order you are expecting.

Comment: As dave_59 says, behaviour in simulation is guaranteed. And it is the job of your synthesiser to create a circuit that behaves exactly the same as the simulation. So there is absolutely no "risk of unknown result in synthesis", because if there were, your synthesiser would have not met that requirement to create a circuit that behaves exactly the same as the simulation.

Comment: Thank you dave - again! 

This was my understanding as well from the IEEE papers, but I needed to have other opinions too.